# Can I get a veteran battlepack in bf4 when I played bf3 on xbox 360 and bf4 on pc?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, battlefield-3, battlefield-4

I haven't gotten a veteran battlepack yet, is it just an error or did I have to play bf4 on xbox 360 or bf3 on pc?

Answer (score 1):

Veteran Battlepacks have not been dished out yet.

Comment: will we get one if we played bf3?

Comment: any non-BF4 game should make you qualify.

Comment: I don't know if this is true, some people have gotten them.  I think it's just another shortcoming/oversight by DICE.

Comment: @turbo, I've seen people posting that they've got their Battlepacks over at the /r/battlefield_4 subreddit last night, so they seem to have started rolling out with Second Assault.

Comment: @tombull89 I've also heard of people getting them on launch day, it's just a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the latest information on this subject from EA:

> Due to a mis-labeling error, Battlefield 3 Players set to receive a
>   Veteran Battlepack for Battlefield 4 upon logging into their game or
>   Battlelog will experience a delay in the delivery of their
>   Battlepacks, but rest assured that appropriate players will still
>   receive their due packs as soon as possible.
>
> Some players may have already received and been able to claim these
>   packs in Battlelog, however players will no longer be able to claim
>   their rewards until this issue has been corrected.

LINK: http://help.ea.com/in/article/battlefield-veteran-battlepack-delay/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I played BF3 on Playstation 3 and I got the veteran battlepack on pc for BF4. 
So I believe so.

Comment: This isn't really an answer